# WP7.1 Manifest Designer

Tags: windows-phone-7, manifest, designer

I have VS 2010 + WP7.1 SDK installed but I can not locate Manifest Designer. I clearly remeber using it some month ago, but now it is entirely gone. I can view only manifest file in xml editor but I can not locate Manifest Designer anywhere. How do I open it? Is there some manual path to it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no manifest Designer in VS2010 only in VS2012